# How to keep accounts for the range of possible numbers on which it is reasonable to make an attempt to guess (Guessing The Number Game on Python)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a beginner in Python , and I'm trying to make an improvement in the guessing the number game.
So far my guessing the number game consists of guessing a secret randomly integer selected by Python in the range of 1 to 100, inclusive, in 10 or fewer attempts.

"x" is the secret number.

The program should ask the user to type a guess "n" for the number "x".

Before typing each guess, the game program count and displays the number of attempts so far. If after 10 attempts have not guessed the number, the program scolds the user with a message like : Unfortunately you have not able to find out the number in 10 attempts.

The "x "number was 40 for give an example so the program looks like these:

```
  Welcome to the game
  The game consists of guessing a secret integer, selected randomly in the range of 1 to 100, in 10 or fewer attempts.
  Attempt 1 ,type your guess: 50          # 50 is the input of the user
```

The program would display something like these:

```
   Attempt 1 ,type your guess: 50 
   x < 50
   Attempt 2 ,type your guess:
```

In addition, the program must keep accounts for the range of possible numbers on
What it is reasonable to make an attempt to guess.

After the first attempt, when the program told you how is "x"  compared to "n", if the guess is not in this range, the program must draw attention with a message like "Ooops, we already knew that x < 60" (for example , if you already typed 50 and the program told you that x < 50)

The thing is that I don't know how to keep accounts for the range of possible numbers on which it is reasonable to make an attempt to guess.

Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
Welcome to the game
The game consists of guessing a secret integer, selected randomly in the range of 1 to 100, in 10 or fewer attempts.
Attempt 1 ,type your guess: 50
x < 50
Attempt 2 ,type your guess: 60
```

If someone type 60 , that is not within the possibilities within which you can find x , so what I want to do , is when something like these happens , the program will print for example :

```
  Attempt 2 ,type your guess: 60
  Ooops, we already knew that x < 60
```

Because the program already told the person that x < 50 , so it is not possible that x = 60

Here's my code so far:

```
 #Guessing the number game
 import random
 attempt = 0
 attempt = attempt + 1

 print('Welcome to the game')
 print('The game consists of guessing a secret integer, selected randomly in  the range of 1 to 100, in 10 or fewer attempts.')

 x = random.randint(1,100)

while attempt < 11:
  print('Attempt', attempt , ',type your guess')
  n = input()
  n = int(n)
  attempt = attempt + 1

  if n < x:
     print('x >',n)     

  if n > x :
     print('x <',n)    

  if n == x:
      break

if n == x:
 attempt = str(attempt)
 print('Congratulations, you have guessed the number in ' , int(attempt) -1 , 'attempts')

if n != x:
  x = str(x)
  print('Unfortunately you have not able to find out the number in 10 attempts. The number was' , x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you needed to do was add `closestmin` and `closestmax` values to the evaluation of the guessed number. Here's my suggestion as to how to do it

```
import random
attempt = 1
closestmin = 0
closestmax = 100

print('Welcome to the game')
print('The game consists of guessing a secret integer, selected randomly in  the range of 1 to 100, in 10 or fewer attempts.')

x = random.randint(1, 100)

for guess in range(10):
    print("Attempt", attempt)
    n = int(input('Type your guess'))


    if n == x:
        attempt = str(attempt)
        print('Congratulations, you have guessed the number in' , attempt, 'attempts')
        break

    elif n < x:
        if n > closestmin:      #if guess is closer than previous closest lowest guess
            closestmin = n      #update closest lowest guess with new number
            print('x >', n)
        elif n < closestmin:
            print("We already know that x <", closestmin)



    elif n > x :
        if n < closestmax:      #if guess is closer than previous closest lowest guess
            closestmax = n      #update closest largest guess with new number
            print('x <', n)
        elif n > closestmax:
            print("We already know that x <", closestmax)

    attempt = attempt + 1
    if attempt > 10:
        print('Unfortunately you have not able to find out the number in 10 attempts. The number was' , x)
        break
```

As you can see, I've added a second if statement that checks to see if the guess was closer than the previous one, and otherwise remind them of their closest guess.

I've also replaced you `while` loop with a `for` loop, for greater simplicity.

Keep coding!